# Rearranging rows in an array in R

Tags: arrays, r

I'm new to R and am certain this is likely a simple question but I can't seem to find the answer. I have an array [36,21,12012]. Is there a simple way to rearrange the array so that the bottom 24 rows are moved above the upper 12.

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you saying you're working with a 9 million cell 3d array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myarray <- array(1:24, c(4,3,2))
#, , 1
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    5    9
#[2,]    2    6   10
#[3,]    3    7   11
#[4,]    4    8   12
#
#, , 2
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   13   17   21
#[2,]   14   18   22
#[3,]   15   19   23
#[4,]   16   20   24

myarray[c(3:4, 1:2),,]
#, , 1
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    3    7   11
#[2,]    4    8   12
#[3,]    1    5    9
#[4,]    2    6   10
#
#, , 2
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   15   19   23
#[2,]   16   20   24
#[3,]   13   17   21
#[4,]   14   18   22
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help Roland. As I thought, nice and easy!